# Did Mark Watney have a beard in the book like he did in the movie?

Tags: the-martian

Was it ever specifically mentioned in the book that he grew out a beard when he left for Ares IV?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't look like it. The only mention I see relating to facial hair is in chapter 9:

> I’ve fallen in to a routine. Every morning I wake up at dawn. First
>   thing I do is check oxygen and CO2 levels. Then I eat a breakfast pack
>   and drink a cup of water. After that, I brush my teeth, using as
>   little water as possible, and shave with an electric razor.

So he *can* shave, if he wants to do so. Other than this I can't find any other reference to beards.

(NASA used to have [wind-up (spring operated) electric-style razors](https://books.google.com/books?id=E0AEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=NASA+wind-up+shaver&source=bl&ots=JOizzVlVo5&sig=4OrX1QA9g1UfiSO5TUna8bWMcm8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAWoVChMIrZPB_K7CyAIVyII-Ch20tgd3#v=onepage&q=NASA%20wind-up%20shaver&f=false) at one time. They were wind-up to eliminate electrical interference.)

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't specifically mentioned ... but *of course* he did.  He was a *space pirate!!*  He also brought with him to Schiaparelli a sharpened piece of MDV strut to use as a cutlass! Yo ho ho!

Comment: The only illegal thing he does is boarding Ares 4. He's not a pirate on Schiaparelli, just a sailor with bad intentions.

Comment: Please allow yourself a sense of humor, like Mark has: he *calls himself a "space pirate"*.  (Both in the book and the movie.)